# get all posts posted in my facebook page and show it to my website

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch all the posts posted on my page and show it on my website. Is it possible? if yes how?

I know that facebook provides embed functionality where you put the post URL and it generates and embed URL for you? but I m looking for something more dynamic where whenever my page loads I get all the posts from my page.

Please bear with me if something is wrong above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like something the Facebook API could achieve.

**Graph API:**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

**User Feed Endpoint:**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed